# Pandas: Split DataFrame between Values of a Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a (large) DataFrame, where one of the columns contains repeating values (see column `'A'` in the example below).
I want to split the DataFrame to multiple frames, containing all rows between some value (e.g. `df['A'] == 0`) and another value (e.g. `df['A'] == 3`), but I want to ignore cases where the opening value appears without the closing one or vice versa (think about it like parenthesis, so case `(...)` is the same as `((...)` and `(...))`).

For this example:

```
a = np.concatenate([np.arange(4), np.arange(5), np.arange(4), np.arange(1), np.arange(4)])
a[5] = 3
b = np.concatenate([np.arange(90, 99), np.arange(9)])
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':a, 'B':b}).T

>> df.head()
   A   B
0  0  90
1  1  91
2  2  92
3  3  93
4  0  94
...
```

I want to get the following DataFrames:

```
>> df1
   A   B
0  0  90
1  1  91
2  2  92
3  3  93

>> df2
   A   B
4  0  94
5  3  95

>> df3
    A  B
9   0  0
10  1  1
11  2  2
12  3  3

>> df4
    A  B
14  0  5
15  1  6
16  2  7
17  3  8
```

Comment: what do you do if you find a 0 value in A columns before the value 3 exemple your A columns like this A=[0,1,2,0,3]

Comment: ignore the first 0, @to_data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's the fastest or simplest way to do it, but here's my solution:

```
def split_by_values(df, colname, start_val, end_val):
    start_idxs = np.nonzero(df[colname] == start_val)[0]
    end_idxs = np.nonzero(df[colname] == end_val_val)[0]
    if len(start_idxs) != len(end_idxs):
        raise AssertionError(f'Number of start indices ({len(start_idxs)}) does not match number of end indices ({len(end_idxs)})')
    start_end_idxs = np.vstack([start_idxs, end_idxs]).T
    df_list = [df.iloc[start:end + 1] for start, end in start_end_idxs]
    return df_list
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this :

```
df.groupby((df["A"] == 0).cumsum())
```